# Two-dimensional distribution and related variance computation

Tags: estimation, sampling, standard-deviation

I have a simple statistical question (forgive me if I use statistical terminology in a wrong way)
Suppose I have a random vector with two components, $(x_1, x_2)$, where $x_1$ can take values from $1$ to $n$ and $x_2$ can take values from $1$ to $m$ 
and I have a two-dimensional distribution $P$ as a $n \times m$ matrix $(i, j)$-th element of $P$ is the probability to observe $(i, j)$ sequence.

Now, I have observations $x^{(k)}_1, x^{(k)}_2$ and can estimate $\widehat{P}$ from the observations (as statistical frequencies)). Now an interesting part. I have a (fixed) vector $v$ and I need to estimate, how well **the matrix-by-vector product** of $\widehat{P}$ by $v$ is estimated:

$$ E || (P - \widehat{P})v ||^2 = ?$$

Comment: Do you just want to compute this expectation, or do you want to find an alternative estimator of $P$ for which this expectation is minimized?

Comment: I want just to compute this expectation.
However, alternative estimator will be also a very interesting problem!

Comment: What order of magnitude do you expect for $n$ and $m$, and for the number of samples? Also, do you have any knowledge about the probabilities - can you maybe bound them away from 0?

Comment: @ErikP. n, m can be large (i.e., n = 100, m = 100) and the number of samples can be K = 10000, i.e. the interesting case is when K is of order of nm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to relabel the number of observations as $T$.

Let $Y_{i,j}^{(t)}=\chi(x_1^{(t)}=i \wedge x_2^{(t)}=j)$ be the indicator function for the event that the $t^{\mathrm{th}}$ observation is $\{ x_1=i\} \cap \{x_2=j\}$. That is, for all $t$, $\Pr(Y_{i,j}^{(t)}=1)=P_{i,j}$. Let $S_{i,j} = \sum_t Y_{i,j}^{(t)}$. Note that $\mathbb{E}\left[S_{i,j}\right] = TP_{i,j}.$

We can now write:

$\quad T^2 \mathbb{E} || (\widehat{P} - P)v ||^2$

$=\sum_i \mathbb{E} \left[ \left(\sum_j (S_{i,j} - TP_{i,j}) v_j \right)^2 \right]$

$= \sum_i \sum_j v_j^2 \mathbb{E}\left[(S_{i,j} - TP_{i,j})^2\right] + 2 \sum_i \sum_{j \not= k} v_j v_k \mathbb{E}\left[( S_{i,j} - TP_{i,j}) (S_{i,k} - TP_{i,k})\right]$

$= \sum_i \sum_j v_j^2 \mathrm{Var}\left(S_{i,j}\right) + 2 \sum_i \sum_{j \not= k} v_j v_k \mathrm{Cov}\left( S_{i,j}, S_{i,k}\right).$

Recognizing that the $S_{i,j}$ variables are jointly [multinomially distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), we obtain

$$T \mathbb{E} || (\widehat{P} - P)v ||^2 = \sum_i \sum_j v_j^2 \left[P_{i,j}(1- P_{i,j})\right] - 2 \sum_i \sum_{j \not= k} v_j v_k \left( P_{i,j}\cdot P_{i,k}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $m$ and $n$ are pretty large, I'd say it is reasonable to consider the entries $\widehat {P_{i,j}}$ as independent $\text{Binomial}(K, P_{i,j})$ variables, divided by $K$. The expectation you're looking at then becomes:

$$\sum_i \mathbb{E} \left(\sum_j (\widehat{P_{i,j}} - P_{i,j}) v_j \right)^2 =
\sum_i \sum_j v_j^2 \mathbb{E}(\widehat{P_{i,j}} - P_{i,j})^2 + \sum_i \sum_{j \not= k} v_j v_k (\mathbb{E} \widehat{P_{i,j}} - P_{i,j}) (\mathbb{E} \widehat{P_{i,k}} - P_{i,k}).$$

Since $\widehat{P_{i,j}}$ is an unbiased estimator of $P_{i,j}$, the last sum is zero, so we are left with the first sum on the right hand side. If $X \tilde\ \text{Binomial}(K, P_{i,j})$, then

$$\mathbb{E}(\widehat{P_{i,j}} - P_{i,j})^2 = \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{K} - P_{i,j}\right)^2 = \frac{\mathbb{E} X^2}{K^2} - 2 \frac{P_{i,j} \mathbb{E}X}{K} + P_{i,j}^2 = \frac{P_{i,j}(K P_{i,j} + 1 - P_{i,j})}{K} - 2 P_{i,j}^2 + P_{i,j}^2 = \frac{P_{i,j}(1 - P_{i,j})}{K}.$$

Substituting this into the first formula, we obtain this result:

$$\mathbb{E}\ \left\Vert (P - \widehat P) v \right\Vert^2 = \frac{\sum_j v_j^2 \sum_i P_{i,j}(1 - P_{i,j})}{K}.$$

Comment: I tried this route, but the assumption that $\widehat{P}_{ij}$ are independent is not always justified (I can not prove any estimates for them), and I even did a randomized check in MATLAB (i.e., estimating the variance over a series of T runs as well), then the difference between the left side and the right side can be quite large. I am just wandering, if there is a way to get an exact formula without any additional assumptions (i.e., valid even for $n=2, m=2$, ok, I am changing the setting :) but I think the message is clear.